# pulling a variable from text file in a sentence

Tags: batch-file

im currently making something along the lines of a sentence generator, it uses text files which have a list of words in them, for example celebrity.txt has a list of celebrities and this script both shuffles the text file into newcelebrity.txt and takes the first one from that list so its different every time, and ive run into a problem, i want it to be one line and that you can call a variable in the sentance youre typing, not break it down as it is right now, is there a way to have it "this $celebrity is really great" as of now, it works like this: https://gyazo.com/9ae8583ed5457709bd1c1dc9cc0cc106 and outputs as this https://gyazo.com/1a5a90f1fbf80faa73d71791a8c1c761, i dont mind the quotation marks at all, its just the way you input it.
Is there any way to make it work like i want it to or is this a limitation of batch files?

```
set /p message=Unity:
set /p input=The variable:
set /p after=Unity:
:gen
setlocal
cd ..
cd rcs
echo doing background work, please wait a few seconds :)
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%input%.txt) do call set "$$%%random%%=%%a"
(for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set $$') do echo(%%b)>new%input%.txt
endlocal
cls
set "File=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\gg\rcs\new%input%.txt"
set /a count=0
echo background work done :)
timeout /t 1 >nul
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File%"') do (
         Set /a count+=1
         Set "output[!count!]=%%a"     
)

For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) Do (
 Call :Action "!output[%%i]!"
 pause
)

Exit
::*******************************************************
:Action
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo %message% %1 %after%
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo if you want to go back and change your inputs type back
echo if you want to continue generating, type gen
echo.
set /p instruction=
goto %instruction%
::*******************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the quotation marks, just use %~1 instead of %1.

I'm assuming, you want to *input* something like 'this $celeb is great' instead of the first three `set /p` lines (as your *output* is already in one line).

I used some fixed variables to keep it short - of course you would fetch them from the user and the text file instead, as you already did.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "count=3"
set "output[3]=John"

set "sentence=this $celeb is great."
REM above would be your 'set /p' instead
call :action "!output[%count%]!"
goto :of

:action
echo !sentence:$celeb=%~1!
```

(just to be clear: `$celeb` is *not* a variable - it's just a string, that we replace later, so from user's perspective, it *behaves* like a variable)

Comment: hey this worked great by itself, but when I tried to intergrate it into my code I ran into a problem, I need the "set output" to be after my shuffling text file script, so it wont give the same answer every time, bit you pointed out in the rem that it would be "above would be your set /p" instead, and the second problem is that I need to state the "$celeb" or in the future, some other string such as "$country" so the script knows what text file to read from, is this a problem with my structuring or is there a workaround? https://pastebin.com/TNxnbXMZ here is all the code as of now

Comment: before set "output[3]=%maker1%", I accidentaly deleted a line of code here before, that states what %maker1% is, which is the text file's first line, but it couldnt find the file, because the script right after makes a new text file which is shuffled with "new{originalname}.txt", and thats the roadblock I hit.